# SSAS 2012 Drillthrough Translations

Tags: ssas, ssas-2012

I have a multi-dimensional cube that contains French translations which are working as expected with both languages (English and French). The cube also contains Drillthrough actions which also work as expected with English.

The problem is when the cube is browsed in French, the drillthroughs still return English. When I run Profiler, I see the localization identifier "" properly set to 1036 - French(France) for the MDX Drillthrough command.

What am I doing wrong?
How to correct this?

Thanks in advance for answering my question.

Answer (score 0):

The translations are on the Caption and I was using the member's Name property with a DrillThrough action. To solve the problem, I create a Cube Action with a Rowset action type and used ASSP library function GetCustomDrillthroughMDX. The command similar to below.

```
    ASSP.GetCustomDrillthroughMDX("   
        caption ([$Interview].[Interview ID])
       ,caption ([$Interview].[Description])
       ,caption ([$InterviewDate].[Date])
       ,caption ([$Category].[Category Level1]) 
       ,caption ([$Category].[Category Level2]) 
       ,caption ([$Category].[Category Level3]) 
       ,caption ([$Category].[Category Level4]) 
       ,caption ([$Category].[Question]) 
       ,caption ([$Category].[Answer]) 
")
```

This allowed me to pull the correct translations.